# Loop while week day + Business hours

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script where it will only run during M-F 8AM-5PM. The problem is after it falls off either 8-5 or M-F `while()` loop it just... doesn't know how to get back into the loop. This makes me think that I may be approaching my script at the wrong angle. Maybe there's a better way of doing this.

The "do something" part is it's comparing file size between the same file at 5 minutes apart. This is for checking if the file is growing/shrinking or not.

```
# Declare current date/time
$Weekday = [int](Get-Date).DayOfWeek
$hour = [int](Get-Date -Format HH)

while (1 -eq 1) {   # always true
    $Weekday = [int](Get-Date).DayOfWeek
    $hour = [int](Get-Date -Format HH)
    while ($Weekday -ge 1 -and $Weekday -le 5) {  # weekday
        $Weekday = [int](get-date).DayOfWeek    # loop check for current day
        while ($hour -ge 8 -and $hour -le 16) { # 8AM-5PM
            $hour = [int](get-date -format HH)  # loop check for current hour
            # Do Something
        }
        else {
            # Sleep until next business hour
            $date = Get-Date
            $date = $date.AddDays(1)
            $mmddyyy = $date.ToString("MM/dd/yyy")
            $nextDy = New-TimeSpan -End "$mmddyyy 08:00"
            Write-Host "Start sleep timer until next 8AM"
            Start-Sleep -Seconds $nextDy.TotalSeconds
        }
    }
    else {
        # Sleep until next business day
        $date = Get-Date
        while ($Date.DayOfWeek -ne "Monday") {$date = $date.AddDays(1)}
        $mmddyyy = $date.ToString("MM/dd/yyy")
        $nextBu = New-TimeSpan -End "$mmddyyy 08:00"
        Write-Host "Start sleep timer until next Monday 8AM"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $nextBu.TotalSeconds
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into cron jobs or the Task Scheduler in Windows?

Comment: What's a cron jobs? I did looked into the task scheduler, but we have not gone that far yet. Eventually we will use task schedule to kill/start the script.

Comment: "Eventually we will use task schedule to kill/start the script." - So why not just do that now rather than creating a problem by doing it the way that you won't be doing it?

Comment: @EBGreen true... I over think my problem.

Comment: According to your code you seem to be under the impression that `while` loops have `else` branches. That is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Try using scheduled task or service.
2. If you want to use a PowerShell script try using this:

   ```
   while ($true)
   {
       #WeekDay
       $Weekday = [int](Get-Date).DayOfWeek #loop check for current day
       $hour = [int](Get-Date -Format HH)
       if ($Weekday -le 5 -and $Weekday -ge 1)
       {
           while ($hour -ge 8 -and $hour -le 16)
           {
               #8AM-5PM
               $hour = [int](Get-Date -Format HH) #loop check for current hour
               #Do Something
           }
       }
       $date = Get-Date
       $date = $date.AddDays(1)
       $mmddyyy = $date.ToString("MM/dd/yyy")
       $nextDy = New-TimeSpan -End "$mmddyyy 08:00"
       Write-Host "Start sleep timer until next 8AM"
       Start-Sleep -Seconds $nextDy.TotalSeconds
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I think you got it totally wrong.

Better you use a simple library function like [TestFileSizeUtil](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00/09/94/83/35/Test-FileSizeUntil.ps1) to [monitor file size](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/candede/2010/01/14/monitor-file-size/) or use WMI like shown [here](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/01/03/pstip-monitor-file-growth-using-wmi/):

```
$query = "Select * from __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 5 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile' AND TargetInstance.Name='C:\\Logs\\test.log'"

Register-WmiEvent -Query $query -Action {
    Write-Host "Current file size is: " $Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.FileSize
    $prevSize = $Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.PreviousInstance.FileSize
    $curSize = $Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.FileSize
    if ($curSize -gt $prevSize) {
        $bytes = $curSize - $prevSize
        Write-Host "File grew by: $bytes bytes"
    } else {
        $bytes = $prevSize - $curSize
        Write-Host "File reduced by: $bytes bytes"
    }
}
```

Then, it should not matter if your script runs all day long.